# Is there a place where I can read or watch to get an accurate TensorFlow code wise explanation?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, resource-request

I have a piece of code and I don't seem to really understand it but I'd love to get a source/link/material that would help me understand the basic functions in TensorFlow. Are there any recommended resources for learning the same?

Comment: there exists abundant amounts of tutorials on tensorflows webpage, maybe start there

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community Anandhu! What do you mean by "accurate tensorflow code wise explanation?". Also, which code are you talking about when you say "I have this code"?

Comment: man i just wanna know how the basic functions of tensorflow works like the model.fit and all those so I was wondering if there are any top recommended sources for this and thanks for the welcome. @nbro

Answer (score 2):

The best resource for learning TensorFlow 1.9 and earlier is this [course](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/syllabus.html) by Stanford. Also additional resources for the entire overview of TensorFlow and its comparisons with NumPy has been made in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6K-MFgIEjc). For hands on models check these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYbVFhK_olY&list=PLSPWNkAMSvv5DKeSVDbEbUKSsK4Z-GgiP) by Sentdex and also some high level [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=er8RQZoX3yk&list=PL9Hr9sNUjfsmEu1ZniY0XpHSzl5uihcXZ) by Hvass Labs.

Comment: NOTE: I have no association with the creator of these aforementioned resources.